# How can I stop Visual Studio from breaking on Exceptions when I have already swallowed them?

Tags: c#

I'm developing an application inside Visual Studio using C#. This is a simple Console application.

In some places, I wish to swallow exceptions. Thus I use an empty `catch` block. It' by design.

When I hit F5, in codes of the `try` block of that `catch` block, when exceptions raise Visual Studio breaks on them.

This behavior is very annoying and reduces our debugging speed. I want those exceptions to not break at all.

How can I do that?

I searched the Options menu and I found nothing.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @NineBerry Visual Studio Community Version 17.4.1

Comment: The answer by EEAH is correct and should help.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `Debug` > `Windows` > `Exception Settings`

A new window will open

[image]

Uncheck `Common Language Runtime Exceptions`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe start the programme without debugging and if your Try block is in a Loop then you should write a continue in the catch block